# Show/Hide Passwords in Flutter's TextFormField

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm working on a TextFormField to accept passwords. I have set the suffix icon to have IconButton child to detect on click events and to toggle the obscuretext attribute of the TextFormField. The callback function for the iconButton gets called but the TextFormField doesn't get repainted. Any ideas on how to solve this?

```
static Widget buildTextFormField(String id, 
                               FormFieldValidator<String> validateField,
                               FormFieldSetter<String> saveField,
                               InputDecoration decoration,
                               EdgeInsetsGeometry paddingInfo,
                               EdgeInsetsGeometry marginInfo,
                               TextInputType keyboardType,
                               {bool obscureField:false, double width:328.0,
                                TextEditingController controller}
  ){
return Container(
  padding: paddingInfo,
  margin: marginInfo,
  width: width,
  child: TextFormField(
    key: Key(id),
    obscureText: obscureField,
    validator: validateField,
    onSaved: saveField,
    keyboardType: keyboardType,
    decoration: decoration,
    controller: controller,
  ),
);
```

}

```
InputDecoration passwordDecoration = InputDecoration(
   hintText: 'Password',
   labelText: 'Enter your password',
   suffixIcon:
      IconButton(
         icon: Icon(
            _passwordVisible ? Icons.visibility : Icons.visibility_off,
            semanticLabel: _passwordVisible ? 'hide password' : 'show password',
         ),
         onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
               _passwordVisible ^= true;
               //print("Icon button pressed! state: $_passwordVisible"); //Confirmed that the _passwordVisible is toggled each time the button is pressed.
            });
         }),
   labelStyle: TextStyle(
      fontFamily: 'Roboto Medium',
      fontSize: 12.0,
      color: Color(0x99000000),
      letterSpacing: 0.4,
   ),
);
final passwordPaddingInfo = const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0, bottom:15.0,
                                                  left: 22.0, right:25.0);
this._passwordField = AdministrationComponents.
buildTextFormField('passwordField', validatePassword,
   (value) => _password = value, passwordDecoration, passwordPaddingInfo,
   null, null, controller:_passwordController,
   obscureField: !_passwordVisible);
```

Comment: Please update your question adding the code instead of the image.

Comment: @diegoveloper please see update. Thanks!

Comment: is your password visible when you press the eye-Icon ? what's the issue? paste your build method

Comment: Are you calling the buildTextFormField in your build() method ?

Comment: @diegoveloper No, it not visible when I press the IconButton. However, I see that the value of _passwordVisible toggles when the button is pressed.

Comment: @ShyjuM yes, I am.

Comment: I am actually calling the buildTextFormField from within the constructor of a class that is derived from State<T>. See the build method below. All the children of the ListView are initialized in the constructor.

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: ListView(
          children: [
            _appLogo,
            _fullnameField,
            _emailField,
            _passwordField,
            _confirmPasswordField,
            _registerButton,
          ],
        )
    );
  }

Comment: working fine for me with your code. https://github.com/shyjuzz/flutter-samples/tree/master/passworddemo

Comment: @ShyjuM Thanks for trying it out. I see what I was doing wrong - I was calling the buildTextFormField in the constructor of my State class and not in the build method. Moving the call to buildTextFormField inside the build method fixed it. Thanks again for all of your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @ShyjuM and @ diegoveloper! I see what I was doing wrong - I was calling the buildTextFormField in the constructor of my State class and not in the build method. Moving the call to buildTextFormField inside the build method fixed it. Thanks again for all of your help!

Answer (score 18):

Try to this

```
 bool _showPassword = false;
  void _togglevisibility() {
    setState(() {
      _showPassword = !_showPassword;
    });
  }
```

Textform field code

```
child: TextFormField(
                                controller: _passwordController,
                                obscureText: !_showPassword,
                                cursorColor: Colors.red,
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  hintText: "Password",
                                  border: InputBorder.none,
                                  suffixIcon: GestureDetector(
                                    onTap: () {
                                      _togglevisibility();
                                    },
                                    child: Icon(
                                      _showPassword ? Icons.visibility : Icons
                                          .visibility_off, color: Colors.red,),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
```

Answer (score 9):

Show/Hide Passwords in Flutter's TextFormField

Step 1:

```
bool _obscureText = true;
```

Step 2:

```
void _toggle() {
    setState(() {
      _obscureText = !_obscureText;
    });
  }
```

Step 3:

```
 TextField(
                controller: password,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
                obscureText: _obscureText,
                decoration: new InputDecoration(
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                  focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
                  enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                  errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
                  disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                  hintText: "Password",
                  suffixIcon: InkWell(
                    onTap: _toggle,
                    child: Icon(
                      _obscureText
                          ? FontAwesomeIcons.eye
                          : FontAwesomeIcons.eyeSlash,
                      size: 15.0,
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

Comment: adding an explanation to your answer would help.

Answer (score 0):

You have some errors in your code.

Replace this :

```
_passwordVisible > Icons.visibility : Icons.visibility_off,
```

and

```
_passwordVisible ^= true;
```

**By this:**

```
_passwordVisible ? Icons.visibility : Icons.visibility_off,
```

and

```
  _passwordVisible = !_passwordVisible;
```

Comment: thanks for catching that. But it was actually a typo from me converting the image I originally posted to text. I have corrected it in the snippet above.

and 

_passwordVisible ^= true; is equivalent to _passwordVisible = !_passwordVisible;

Comment: thanks @diegoveloper for trying it out. I see what I was doing wrong - I was calling the buildTextFormField in the constructor of my State class and not in the build method. Moving the call to buildTextFormField inside the build method fixed it. Thanks again for all of your help!

Answer (score -1):

This is the Password dart i use

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class LoginPass extends StatefulWidget {
LoginPass(this.controllerUpass);

  final Function controllerUpass;

  @override
  _LoginPassState createState() => _LoginPassState();
}

class _LoginPassState extends State<LoginPass> {
  bool _isHidden = true;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 30, 0, 10),
      child: Container(
        height: 35,
        child: Center(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
            child: TextField(
              obscureText: _isHidden,
              onChanged: (value) {
                widget.controllerUpass(value);
              },
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Password',
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                  focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
                  enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                  errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
                  disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                  suffixIcon: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {
                        _isHidden = !_isHidden;
                      });
                    },
                    child: _isHidden
                        ? Icon(
                            Icons.remove_red_eye_sharp,
                            color: Colors.blue,
                          )
                        : Icon(
                            Icons.remove_red_eye,
                            color: Colors.red,
                          ),
                  )),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
            BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.black26,
              spreadRadius: 1,
              blurRadius: 3,
              offset: Offset(0, 3),
            ),
          ],
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(3)),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In Main call

```
LoginPass(controllerUpass),
```

Comment: child: Icon(_isHidden?Icons.visibility:Icons.visibility_off)

this seems more efficient